# Hide the last character in div if the last character was not displayed completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has a line of text like this:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 20px; white-space: nowrap; width: 27px; font-size: 14px">
  HHHAASDAS
</div>
```

The div has a width of `27px`, and hides the superfluous characters by `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap`.

In this example the last characters display on the screen is `A`. However, the `A` did not display completely, I can only see the half of this character. How can I hide the last character if the last character doesn't display completely?

Comment: Did you already try [`text-overflow: ""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use CSS [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) property to allow break lines within words.
2. Use [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) equal to the height so that the next line starts outside the visible area.
3. Use JavaScript/jQuery to replace all whitespace with non-breaking whitespace.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".test").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/\s+/g, "\u00A0");
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 27px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">HHHAASDAS</div>
<div class="test">H HHAA SDAS</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 20px; white-space: nowrap; width: 27px; font-size: 14px">
    HHHAASDAS
</div>
<p class="result"></p>

    var myString = $.trim($( "div" ).html());
    var lastString = myString.slice(0, -1); 
    alert(lastString);
    $( ".result" ).html(lastString);
```

**Demo**http://jsfiddle.net/en1tcguj/3/

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;`
works like this

if HHHAASDAS does not fit compleatle then it will be desplayed as

HHA...

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 20px; white-space: nowrap; width: 27px; font-size: 14px">
  HHHAASDAS
</div>
```